# PostMessage does not seem to be working

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pinvoke, sendmessage, postmessage

I am trying to use PostMessage to send a tab key.

Here is my code:

```
// This class allows us to send a tab key when the the enter key
//  is pressed for the mooseworks mask control.   
public class MaskKeyControl : MaskedEdit
{
//  [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
//  static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    // I am calling this on a Windows Mobile device so the dll is coredll.dll
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

    public const Int32 VK_TAB = 0x09;
    public const Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
            return;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\r') 
            e.Handled = true;
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

When I press enter the code gets called, but nothing happens.  Then I press TAB and it works fine.  (So there is something wrong with my sending of the Tab Message.)

Comment: I added the compact-framework tag, some of the answers you have are not targetting the compact framework.

Comment: @Chris Taylor - Thanks.  I should have added that when I asked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't post windows messages related to user input directly to windows controls.  Rather, if you want to simulate input, you should rely on the [SendInput API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) instead to send the key presses.

Also, as Chris Taylor mentions in his comment, the [SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(VS.90).aspx) can be used to send key inputs to an application in the event that you want to use an existing managed wrapper (instead of calling SendInput function yourself through the P/Invoke layer).

Comment: For manageded code SendKeys might be a better option.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

Comment: I ended up using the keybd_event function.  It is in the coredll.dll that is on the Windows Mobile device.  This was the closest to that, so I am giving it the nod.

Answer (score 2):

PostMessage on key events does really really odd things.

In this case, maybe SendMessage with KEYDOWN, KEYPRESS, KEYUP (three calls) might work better.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to sending input messages to the control, you could be more explicit and do the following.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
  {
    if (Parent != null)
    {
      Control nextControl = Parent.GetNextControl(this, true);
      if (nextControl != null)
      {
        nextControl.Focus();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

This will set the focus to the next control on the parent when the enter key is pressed.